# git bash npm error

Tags: git, npm, git-bash

I'm using Win 7, 64 bit.

in Git Bash command when i write
**npm** it could return error.

I uninstall/install check it. But nothing changed.

I couldnt find a solution. In node command it is working.

```
$ npm

c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ansi\lib\newlines.js:2
function result = truth_table_chart_man(methodName, objectId, varargin)
                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\ansi\lib\ansi.js:14:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```